# como modificar determinado valor ou letra dentro de um texto python

Tags: python

eu tenho o seguinte texto

```
1050 = N X 0
1260 = N X 0
1470 = N X 0
1680 = N X 0
1890 = N X 0
2100 = N X 0
2310 = N X 0
2520 = N X 0
2730 = N X 0
2940 = N X 0
3150 = N X 0
3360 = N X 0
3570 = N X 0
```

onde ta "X" quero subistituir por um numero randomico de zero a nove

```
 (random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

pra ficar assim

```
1050 = N 0 0
1260 = N 1 0
1470 = N 4 0
1680 = N 6 0
1890 = N 8 0
2100 = N 3 0
2310 = N 1 0
2520 = N 1 0
2730 = N 6 0
2940 = N 5 0
3150 = N 3 0
3360 = N 2 0
3570 = N 8 0
```

eu nao to sabendo aplicar

Comment: Lê o arquivo linha a linha (`open`), sorteie um número (`random.choice`), substitua o valor de `X` (`str.replace`) e escreva no arquivo (`f.write`). Quer tentar?

Comment: vou tentar fazer e colo o resultado aqui

Comment: Eu n consegui eu tentei assim   import random

open ('/Users/Felipe/Desktop/GH.txt','r')

MM = (random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))


GH.replace('X','MM')